# How to change target of the Spring Cloud Stream Kafka binder?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Using Spring cloud Stream 2.1.4 with Spring Boot 2.1.10, I'm trying to target a local instance of Kafka.
This is an extract of my projetc configuation so far:

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
spring.kafka.streams.bootstrap-servers=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=localhost:2181
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.brokers=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.zkNodes=localhost:2181
```

But the binder keeps on calling a wrong target :

```
java.io.IOException: Can't resolve address: kafka.example.com:9092
```

How can can I specify the target if those properties won't do he trick?
More, I deploy the Kafka instance through a Docker Bitnami image and I'd prefer not to use SSL configuration (see PLAINTEXT protocol) but I'm don't find properties for basic credentials login. Does anyone know if this is hopeless?

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services: 
  zookeeper:
    image: bitnami/zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      - ZOO_ENABLE_AUTH=yes
      - ZOO_SERVER_USERS=kafka
      - ZOO_SERVER_PASSWORDS=kafka_password
    networks:
      - kafka-net
  kafka:
    image: bitnami/kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka
    hostname: kafka.example.com
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_USER=kafka
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_PASSWORD=kafka_password
    networks:
      - kafka-net
networks:
  kafka-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've used Bitnami images just fine... You should test kafka-console-producer first, but please show your docker run command

Comment: Hello, I'm using a docker-compose module (added to the question) ; just running docker-compose up -d

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but, FYI, you no longer need `zkNodes` properties. SCSt doesn't talk to zookeeper.

Comment: You're right, just trying things gathered round :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right: got this to work by looking twice to the "dockerfile" (thx to cricket_007):

```
kafka:
...
    hostname: localhost
```

For the record: I could get rid of all properties above, default being for Kafka localhost:9092

Comment: `hostname` isn't what you want, though. You should be using `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` env-var

Comment: For the record, I unsuccessfully tried to change the config as following:

  kafka:
    ...
    hostname: kafka
    ...
    environment:
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092

Comment: You need to advertise localhost, not the Docker service name unless your code is running in a container on the same Docker network where DNS lookups will work

Answer (score 1):

The `hostname` isn't the issue, rahter the advertised listeners `protocol//:port` mapping that causes the hostname to be advertised, by default. You should change that, rather than the hostname.

```
  kafka:
    image: bitnami/kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka
    hostname: kafka.example.com # <--- Here's what you are getting in the request
    ...
    environment:
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092 # <--- This returns the hostname to the clients
```

If you plan on running your code **outside** of another container, you should advertise `localhost` in addition to, or instead of the container hostname.

[One year later, my comment still is not been merged into the bitnami README](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka/issues/29#issuecomment-435216430), where I was able to get it working with the following vars (changed to match your deployment)

```
KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://:9092
KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka.example.com:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I was wondering: since changing the hostname fixed the issue, don't you think that those other variables are auto-completed from that single value anyways?

Comment: FYI I'm not planning on running my app into the container, I think Kafka will always better be deployed on its own. This is only for proof of concept purpose. But I understand that I would have to get a domain name and set it up around, if I wanted to run that containers on another machine, right?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with deploying your application as a container. I was just mentioning it because docker maintains its own networking bridge. If nothing is containerized, then you don't need to deal with port mappings and multiple interfaces. Regarding a domain, most modern routers have a setting for that